# how to handle children events reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

in Plain JS I can say  `const corners = document.querySelectorAll('.corner')` then I can add event listener to it.

#### My question is

- Haw can I do that with react ?
- Is it posibale to add on function in the parent `<div>` and program
  it to add event listener for of its Childs

---

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import '../css/style.css'

function Boxshape() {


      return (
            <div
                  className='item'>
                  <div className='box'>
                        <div
                              onMouseOver={() => console.log('mouse over element A')}
                              className='corner A'></div>
                        <div className='corner B'></div>
                        <div className='corner C'></div>
                        <div className='corner D'></div>
                  </div>
            </div>
      )
}

export default Boxshape
```

- this is my css just in case you are carries

```
.item{
      height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: aquamarine;
}
.corner{
      position: absolute;
      width: 10px;
      height: 10px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      background-color: black;
      z-index: 2;
}

.A{
      top:-1px;
      left: -1px;
      cursor: nw-resize;
}
.B{
      top:-1px;
      right: -1px;
      cursor: ne-resize;
}
.C{
      bottom:-1px;
      left: -1px;
      cursor: sw-resize;
}
.D{
      bottom:-1px;
      right: -1px;
      cursor: se-resize;
}
```

Comment: You can take advantage of [event bubbling](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing) and add a event listener on the common ancestor element of all the elements on which you want to add a event listener and then using [Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) object, handle the event appropriately.

Comment: @Yousaf that is really cool idea here [https://plnkr.co/edit/eiVixZwxlxFG9dyx?p=preview&preview], but how they use `form.onclick = function(){}` without defining `form`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can attach an `onmouseover` event to the parent and retrieve the targets. Here is a plain HTML snippet, but you can translate this to React.

```js
function logCorner(e) {
  const targetClassNames = e.target.className;
  if (targetClassNames.includes('corner')) {
    console.log(`mouse over ${targetClassNames}`)
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  padding:2rem;
}
.item{
      height: 500px;
      width: 500px;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: aquamarine;
}

.corner{
      position: absolute;
      width: 10px;
      height: 10px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      background-color: black;
      z-index: 2;
}

.A{
      top:0px;
      left: 0px;
      cursor: nw-resize;
}
.B{
      top:0px;
      right: 0px;
      cursor: ne-resize;
}
.C{
      bottom:0px;
      left: 0px;
      cursor: sw-resize;
}
.D{
      bottom:0px;
      right: 0px;
      cursor: se-resize;
}
```

```html
<div className='item'>
  <div class='box' onmouseover="logCorner(event)">
    <div class='corner A'></div>
    <div class='corner B'></div>
    <div class='corner C'></div>
    <div class='corner D'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Depending on how complex your corner divs become you can adopt a variety of patterns.

Here is a simple example that abstracts the corner divs to a Handle component

```
function Boxshape() {

  return (
    <div className='item'>
      <div className='box'>
        <Handle className="A" />
        <Handle className="B" />
        <Handle className="C" />
        <Handle className="D" />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

function Handle({className}) {

  const mouseOverHandler = () => {
    console.log(`mouse over: ${className}`)
  }

  return (
    <div
      onMouseOver={mouseOverHandler}
      className={`corner ${className}`}></div>
  )
}

export default Boxshape
```

Comment: I don't want to activate the function every time the mouse over the box div I want to activate it only when the mouse over the divs with the class name corner

Comment: Edited to check for `corner` in classNames. But also see my addition about abstracting  the corners into their own component.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you can pass in the event in the element tag, and then make a function (you decide the functions name), and then you can pass in the function into the element, by saying this.

don't do () cause we only log it once on click, also we put it in brackets, cause it's a js code, not a react.

---

```
function handleClick() {
 console.log('Don\'t you dare click me lol')
};

<button onClick={handleClick}>I\'m a button</button>
```